# Printing values of arrays inside splitted numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, syntax

I have an numpy array like `rawarrayofvalues = [1, 2, 3, 4, ... nvalues]`. Then, I split it into N arrays with the `numpy.split` method. So I get N different arrays splitted from the big `rawarrayofvalues`.

After the splitting, I would like to get a specific value from a specific array in order to my calculations on them.

Here is kind of a pseudo-code of how the thing would run, with for example nvalues = 40 and N = 4 :

```
import numpy as np
rawarrayofvalues = np.arange(1, 41) 
rawarraysplit = np.split(rawarrayofvalues, 4)

#Then my sort of pseudo-code starts

for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(1,(rawarraysplit[i].size)-1):
        variation = (rawarraysplit[i][j-1] - rawarraysplit[i][j+1]) / (rawarraysplit[i][j-1] + rawarraysplit[i][j+1])
```

I don't find the correct syntax for the calculation, the interpreter gives my the error:

> IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10

So my question is: **What is the best way to retrieve an indexed value inside an array which is already indexed in one array?**

I am a Python-newbie and a former Matlab-Octave user... So it might not be the best pythonic way to do what I want here.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you would like to get as a result?

Comment: I ran your code and got no error...

Comment: In python indexing of a list or array dimension of size 10, runs from 0 to 9.

Comment: @hpaulj That's true I forgot it thanks for the reminder !

Comment: @mkrieger1 In fact I would like to calculate the gradient a designated number of an array, as the array would represent a discretization of a function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure as to what operation you're intending to do inside the loop. You're dividing the same value again which will always result in variable 'variation' being 1.
 You had asked for the syntax so I'm sharing this:

```
import numpy as np
rawarrayofvalues = np.arange(1, 41) 
rawarraysplit = np.split(rawarrayofvalues, 4)

# Then my sort of pseudo-code starts

for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(1,(rawarraysplit[i].size)-1):
        variation = (rawarraysplit[i][j-1] - rawarraysplit[i][j+1]) / (rawarraysplit[i][j-1] - rawarraysplit[i][j+1])
```

If this doesn't answer your question, please elaborate more on the calculation part.

Comment: Thanks for your aswer Raghul Raj ! Indeed, my calculation was senseless because of a typo in my post (denominator was a + sign and not a - sign). I corrected my post consequently.